# How is TfL underground 'capping' calculated if I pay for multiple people's tickets?

Tags: london, payment-cards, price, tfl

Say I buy an underground ticket with contactless payment for myself and my partner.  Do both purchases count towards the cap?

Or is this not allowed?

Comment: Pretty sure you need one card or ticket per person

Comment: @gagravarr even if I pay for both? Is there no way round it? I'm not trying to get around the caso but I know this would be the easiest way for me to pay.

Comment: I am pretty certain that the system won't let you touch-in the second time with the same card until you touch-out with that card first.

Comment: Ok,  @aleksg if that's how it works,  I'll have to work with it,  not around it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### One Person per Journey for all Contactless Methods

To add on to @[MarkMayo's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/42069/22140), the same rules apply for payment across all contactless methods (Oyster and Contactless-card): **you can pay for only one person per journey with contactless methods**. Quoting from [TFL's website on the topic](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/contactless/how-to-use-it#on-this-page-1):

> #### Touching in and out
>
> [...]
>
> Like Oyster, you can only pay for one person per journey with a contactless payment card. If you are travelling in a group, each person will need a separate contactless payment card or other method of payment.

### Lending your Oyster Card

You can however lend your oyster card to another person, provided only one person uses it for one journey, if you meet certain conditions (quoted from [TFL's website on the topic](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/oyster/what-is-oyster#on-this-page-3)):

> #### Lending your Oyster card to others
>
> If your Oyster card only has adult rate pay as you go credit on it, you can lend it to someone else, even if the card is registered in your name.
>
> An Oyster card can't be used by anyone other than the registered user if it has one of the following on it:
>
> - Travelcard or Bus & Tram Pass season ticket
> - Jobcentre Plus Travel Discount
> - Bus & Tram discount
> - National Railcard discount

Answer (score 21):

If you try and use the contactless Oyster twice in a row (ie to let a second person through on your card) for a trip from A to B, it'll error.  You're required to touch out first before you can touch in again, and then the first person wouldn't be allowed to travel as they've touched out at A.

Source: [TFL official site](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/oyster/using-your-oyster-card#on-this-page-5):

> ### Number of people using an Oyster card
>
> Only one Oyster card can be used per person per journey. That means if
>   you are travelling in a group, each person will have to use a separate
>   Oyster card, or find another way to pay for their journey.

Second Source: I've tried this.  And asked about it at the time.  You need one card for each travelling passenger.

Third source : [tripadvisor thread on this same topic](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g186338-i17-k5247202-Can_1_oyster_card_be_used_by_2_people-London_England.html)

Note: This is for Oyster cards, the primary TFL cards when I was in London. For other recent contactless cards, [you'll need to see the TFL site on these here](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/contactless/how-to-use-it#on-this-page-1).

Comment: I will take it as read that this is the same for contactless payment as well?  Thanks.

Comment: Mark, FYI, you are only describing Oyster payments here. Contactless is similar (and the answer is the same), but not identical. JoErNanO's answer covers that...

Comment: @AndrewFerrier interesting, I've left London since they had those, I'll update.

Comment: @MarkMayo, I thought that might be it. You can learn more here: http://www.tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/contactless